# Is $\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x}x\, dx$ not a well-defined integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the integral

$$\int_a^bx\, dx$$

where $a=\sin x$, and $b=\cos x$.

How can we evaluate this particular integral, if $a$ and $b$ are both functions of $x$, which is the variable with respect to which we are integrating?

Answer (score 28):

The variable inside the integral is a "dummy" in that it could be replaced by any other symbol. I think you could interpret $$\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} x \, dx$$ as a sloppy way of writing, but having the same meaning as, $$\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} y \, dy.$$

Answer (score 6):

Here is another interpretation.

Formally if $b\geq a$ then $\int_a^bxdx$ is a notation for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbf1_{(a,b]}(x)xdx$.

Applying that here leads to: $$\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x}xdx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbf1_{(\sin x,\cos x]}(x)xdx$$

I do not dare to say that this is the correct way of interpreting, but it illustrates at least that your question is a good question.

Personally I go for the interpretation of Umberto.

Comment: +1, this makes sense to the "incorrect" notation, so it seems fine for the case

Comment: Why did you bold $1$? Is it a vector?

Comment: It's a notational way of reminding us that it's a function and not a value. I've seen it in a few analysis textbooks.

Comment: +1 This is almost certainly not what is intended, but I like it :)

Comment: If someone is asking this question, they're at the level of introductory calculus. Confusing them with analysis will not be helpful. It is a near-certainty that they need the "dummy variable" answer.

Comment: @manooooh the notation $\mathbf 1_A$ represent the [indicator function of the set $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Comment: @Masacroso wow, that's amazing, thanks!! Do you find something in common with a [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws)?

Comment: @manooooh well, boolean functions and indicator functions share the same image set $\{0,1\}$. I dont know if they are related in any other way

Comment: @drhab: I think an *indefinite* integral is not an appropriate replacement. It should be rather $\int_{a}^b x\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{(a,b]}x\,dx$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer You have a point there, and I repaired. The thing is that I am (perhaps too much) used to measure theory where we just write $\int f$ or $\int fd\lambda$ or even $\lambda(f)$.

Comment: @drhab: I see your point (and I agree :-)). I just thought, since your answer belongs to the top-voted answers a little more rigor might by helpful for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The *particular* expression 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x}x\,dx\tag{1}
\end{align*} is not a well-defined integral, since (1) is not a valid expression.

- We have  inside the integral the integration variable $x$, indicated by $dx$. This kind of variable is called a *[bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)* variable, similarly as the index $i$ in $\sum_{i=0}^n i$.
- On the other hand $x$ is also used in the upper and lower limit of the integral, i.e. it is used as *[free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)* variable, similarly as the variable $n$ in $\sum_{i=0}^ni$.

> Since a variable can be only either bound or free within its scope (i.e. the range of validity of the variable) the expression (1) is not valid.

*Hint:* Based on experience we sometimes identify typos and are inclined to *correct* them with something meaningful. Nevertheless we have to be careful when doing so and when we are in doubt, we shouldn't do anything which can't be  justified by mathematical rules.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter. Just your final solution will also be a function of x.

Proceed the usual way: find the indefinite integral $$\int  xdx=\frac{x^2}{2}$$
put limits: $a=\sin(x)$ and $b=\cos(x)$
$$=\frac{\cos^2x}{2}-\frac{\sin^2x}{2}$$
$$=\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Umberto P. you could also view it as:

$\int_A f(x) dx$ where $A$ is a set, for example an area or volume, that is further distorted by your function $f(x)$.

In your case you would simply plug in your constraints: $A = \{a \in \mathbb{R} | \sin(x) \le a \le \cos(x) \}$ and for $f(x)$ you have of course: $f(x) = x$

Comment: If someone is asking this question, they're at the level of introductory calculus. Confusing them with analysis will not be helpful. It is a near-certainty that they need the "dummy variable" answer.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to actually evaluating the integral, I think that I would interpret it the same as `drhab`, that:

$$\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x}xdx=\int\mathbf1_{(\sin x,\cos x]}(x)xdx$$

and given that:

$$\int x\ dx \implies f(x) = F'(x) = x$$

we can then do (where $C$ is the [constant of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration)):

$$\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} x \, dx = \frac{x^2}{2} + C$$

and then:

$$\frac{x^2}{2} \bigm|_{sin\ x}^{cos\ x}\ =\ \frac{(cos\ x)^2}{2}\ -\ \frac{(sin\ x)^2}{2}\ =\ \frac{(cos\ x)^2-(sin\ x)^2}{2}$$

finally, simplify:

$$\frac{(cos\ x)^2-(sin\ x)^2}{2}=\frac{cos\ 2x}{2}$$